# WPF Application with Bing Maps Control painfully slow on startup

Tags: wpf, performance, bing

I currently work on a WPF application that has mapping support. I use the Bing Maps WPF Control (from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27165) to help with the mapping but now there is a pretty big problem:

The application takes quite some time to start up because the Bing Maps Control retrieves all the initial data to display the map.

The mapping part of my application is only rarely needed and so it would be pretty bad to have slow start up for a feature that is not even used every time so I initially set the control's visibility to "Collapsed" in the hope that then no requests would be made, but that doesn't help.

Is there a way to explicitly initialize the Bing Maps control when I want to use it and not at application start up?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started using the Bing maps control and have also come across the same issue. It's not elegant, but I managed to get around it by manually creating the `Map` control when I need it.

In my case, the map is the main focus of my application, so I need to load it almost instantly. Since I want the application itself to fully render straight away (so the user knows what's going on), I defer creation of the `Map` control until the content is rendered in the `MainWindow`. You can achieve this using something like:

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="MapPanel">

    <!-- Placeholder text while the map is loading -->
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="Loading map..." />
</Grid>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnContentRendered(e);

    // Change the cursor to a waiting cursor so the user knows we are loading something
    var previousCursor = Cursor;
    Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

    // Load the application Id credentials required for the Bing map
    var provider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider(Properties.Resources.BingMapsAPIKey);

    // Set up the Bing map control
    var map = new Map();
    map.Mode = new AerialMode(labels: true);
    map.CredentialsProvider = provider;
    map.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    map.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

    // Render the map control over the top of the loading text in the map panel
    MapPanel.Children.Add(map);

    // Reset the application cursor
    Cursor = previousCursor;
}
```

For your scenario, you don't necessarily need to load the `Map` control at this point. You could, instead, have the control lazily loaded so you essentially notify the host control when the map is required and load it at that point if it has not already been loaded.

Hope that helps.